# Return array instead of object in serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

Have any way to return on `has_many :roles` a array instead of object?

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :nickname, :image, :roles

  has_many :roles
end
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own custom methods in the serializer and use those as attributes

```
class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :role_names

  def role_names
    object.roles.map(&:name)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You usually use [includes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/includes) for that. I'm not that familiar with using serializers though.